# Linking Gecode on OS/X

Tags: linker-errors, gecode

The Gecode (4.3.0) documentation specifies that after installing Gecode on Mac, you can compile and link the examples as follows:

```
￼g++ -O3 -c money.cpp
g++ -framework gecode -o money money.o
```

The compilation succeeds but linking fails with:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Gecode::Gist::TextOutput::TextOutput(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      void Gecode::Driver::ScriptBase<Gecode::Space>::runMeta<Money, Gecode::DFS, Gecode::Options, Gecode::Driver::EngineToMeta>(Gecode::Options const&, Money*) in money.o
      void Gecode::Driver::ScriptBase<Gecode::Space>::runMeta<Money, Gecode::DFS, Gecode::Options, Gecode::RBS>(Gecode::Options const&, Money*) in money.o
  "Gecode::Driver::stop(Gecode::Support::Timer&, std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&)", referenced from:
      void Gecode::Driver::ScriptBase<Gecode::Space>::runMeta<Money, Gecode::DFS, Gecode::Options, Gecode::Driver::EngineToMeta>(Gecode::Options const&, Money*) in money.o
      void Gecode::Driver::ScriptBase<Gecode::Space>::runMeta<Money, Gecode::DFS, Gecode::Options, Gecode::RBS>(Gecode::Options const&, Money*) in money.o
  "Gecode::branch(Gecode::Home, Gecode::IntVarArgs const&, Gecode::IntVarBranch, Gecode::IntValBranch, bool (*)(Gecode::Space const&, Gecode::IntVar, int), void (*)(Gecode::Space const&, Gecode::BrancherHandle const&, unsigned int, Gecode::IntVar, int, int const&, std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&))", referenced from:
      Money::Money(Gecode::Options const&) in money.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Any idea how to resolve this ?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. Interestingly all source files from the examples folder in Gecode were compiled and linked successfully during compiling Gecode. After trying all sorts of include paths, library paths and library names I gave up and did some research.

It seems the issue stems from compiling Gecode itself. If you compile/link using the default Xcode setup, i.e. you use the gcc (4.2.1) symlink that calls clang (Apple LLVM 6.0), you should make sure that both Gecode and your programs use the same standard libraries. That's because there are old binaries (originally used with native gcc) and newer ones.

I compiled Gecode using gcc 4.9.2 (using MacPorts). For some reason I switched back to gcc 4.2.1/clang.
In order to compile my Gecode programs I had to add `-stdlib=libstdc++` to compile/link instructions. This links to the older binaries, whereas `stdlib=libc++` links to the newer ones.
Compiling Send-More-Money would look like this:

```
g++ -c -stdlib=libstdc++ -I/usr/local/include money.cpp
g++ -stdlib=libstdc++ -L/usr/local/lib money.o -lgecodedriver -lgecodesearch -lgecodeminimodel -lgecodeint -lgecodekernel -lgecodesupport
```

Compiling Gecode programs with gcc 4.9.2 on the other hand was simple. In fact newer versions of g++ do not even accept the option `-stdlib`. Therefore it was just

```
g++ -c -I/usr/local/include money.cpp
g++ -L/usr/local/lib money.o -lgecodedriver -lgecodesearch -lgecodeminimodel -lgecodeint -lgecodekernel -lgecodesupport
```

That's all there is to it. Credit goes to one Marco Correia (see [gecode mailing list](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.gecode.user/3975)).

Answer (score 0):

You may use the Linux command inside the documentation to link the dylibs, such as:

1. `setevn LD_LIBRARY_PATH <dir`,e.g.: /usr/local/>
2. `g++ -I <dir>/include -c send-more-money.cpp`
3. `g++ -o send-more-money -L<dir>/lib send-more-money.o -lgecodesearch -lgecodeint -lgecodekernel -lgecodesupport`